# Erlang: MNesia: Implementing redundancy?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, redundancy

I have an application developed with Erlang / MNesia and I am trying to implement redundancy for MNesia.

I want to add - remove nodes dynamically in runtime and handle synchronization of tables for every new joining node.

What is the best way to implement this using Erlang and MNesia?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to implement anything - mnesia already has these features. You can add and remove nodes from a mnesia cluster at runtime, add and remove table copies from nodes within the cluster, and `mnesia:wait_for_tables/2` will let you cope with synchronization while adding nodes or table copies. Have a look at the [mnesia documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html) for more information.